# Something off with survreg in R?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, weibull

While trying to fit a Weibull proportional hazard model to`gehan` data in R, I noticed that changing the order of the`gehan` data changes the output.

```
library(MASS)
library(survival)
attach(gehan)

survreg(Surv(time, cens) ~ treat, gehan, dist = "weibull")
```

produces the output below:

```
Call:
survreg(formula = Surv(time, cens) ~ treat, data = gehan, dist = "weibull")

Coefficients:
 (Intercept) treatcontrol 
 3.515687    -1.267335 

Scale= 0.7321944 

Loglik(model)= -106.6   Loglik(intercept only)= -116.4
Chisq= 19.65 on 1 degrees of freedom, p= 9.3e-06 
n= 42
```

However, when I enter the data into R manually,

```
control <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,8,8,8,8,11,11,12,12,15,17,22,23)
control.status <- c(rep(1,21))
treatment <- c(6,6,6,6,7,9,10,10,11,13,16,17,19,20,22,23,25,32,32,34,35)
treatment.status <- c(1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)

new.time <- c(control,treatment)
new.status <- c(control.status,treatment.status)
group <- as.factor(c(rep("control",21),rep("treatment",21)))
parametrik.surv <- Surv(new.time, new.status)
parametrik.fit <- survreg( parametrik.surv  ~ group, dist="w")
```

Here is a slightly different output:

```
 Call:
survreg(formula = parametrik.surv ~ group, dist = "w")

Coefficients:
(Intercept) grouptreatment 
  2.248352       1.267335 

Scale= 0.7321944 

Loglik(model)= -106.6   Loglik(intercept only)= -116.4
Chisq= 19.65 on 1 degrees of freedom, p= 9.3e-06 
n= 42
```

In addition, in a book beta_0, beta_1 and scale are given as 0.98 , 1.27 and 1.37 respectively. Any idea what causes this?

Comment: `survreg( parametrik.surv ~ relevel(group, ref = 'treatment'), dist="w")`

Comment: @rawr, you code does not produce the results I need (0.98 , 1.27 and 1.37).

Comment: your question was why dont these two match, I showed you how to make them match. there is no way for us to answer your other question

Answer (score 2):

You renamed the treatments so it's using "control" as the reference group in one model and "6-MP" as the reference group in the other.

Comment: What do you suggest to get the results in the book (beta_0, beta_1 and scale  0.98 , 1.27 and 1.37 respectively.)